# In WPF, how can I inherit from ToolBar AND have a XAML file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I can inherit and enhance the ToolBar class by creating a plain C# class, then doing this:

```
public class NiceToolBar : ToolBar
{
    private ToolBarTray mainToolBarTray;

    public NiceToolBar()
    {
        mainToolBarTray = new ToolBarTray();

        mainToolBarTray.IsLocked = true;
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
        ...
```

But this forces me to manipulate all my controls in **code** like this:

```
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
toolBar.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
toolBar.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = label;
tb.Margin = new Thickness { Top = 3, Left = 3, Bottom = 3, Right = 10 };

Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/computer.png", UriKind.Relative));

sp.Children.Add(image);
sp.Children.Add(tb);
toolBar.Items.Add(sp);
```

What I really need is **XAML** to do this tedious parameter assigning and layout.

So I create a **new User Control** and change the code behind to inherit ToolBar like this:

```
public partial class SmartToolBar : ToolBar
{
    public SmartToolBar(string label)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TheLabel.Text = label;
    }
}
```

And in my XAML I put this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestUserControl.Helpers.SmartToolBar"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="Images/computer.png"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TheLabel"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

But when I run it, I get the error:

> Partial declaration of
>   "TestCallConstructor.Helpers.SmartToolBar"
>   may not define different basis classes

How can I have my user control **with** XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for Custom Controls (not UserControl). When you write a custom control you can specify its default view (i.e. XAML).

You can google how to create custom controls in WPF, but here is one link I googled out for you [How to Create a WPF Custom Control](http://www.wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html).

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 3):

You're not writing a `UserControl` if you're inheriting from `ToolBar`, since `ToolBar` does not inherit from `UserControl`. Your XAML is specifying the base class as `UserControl` whilst your C# is specifying `ToolBar`. Obviously there is a conflict there.

I don't understand your premise for doing this stuff in code behind in the first place. Why not just bind your `ToolBar`'s `ItemsSource` to your collection of items, and use the usual `ItemsControl` properties to control the rendering?